# Function in a class that doesn't take a variable. but reads/prints an array

Tags: c++, file, io, fstream

So I have a class:

```
class myClass {
public:
    void readFile();

private:
    int sPerDay[10];

};
```

And I want this function to read/print the array of the text file (a bunch of numbers 10 lines long)

```
void myClass::readFile()
{

    ifstream read("numbers.txt");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        read>>sPerDay[i];

    for (int i = 0;i<10;i++) {
        cout << sPerDay[i];
    }
}
```

Output is a bunch of random numbers. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What does `numbers.txt` look like?

Comment: 10 lines of single digit numbers

Comment: You should check if the file is opened correctly

Comment: figured it out. thanks all. XCode must have its settings changed to allow files to be accessed from a custom directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not sure whether the file exists, or whether it is in the same directory as your executable, modify your code to [check if the file opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255339/checking-if-a-file-opened-successfully-with-ifstream), like this for example:

```
void readFile() {
    ifstream read("numbersd.txt");
    if(!read) { cerr << "File didn't open..Does it exist?" << endl; return; }
    ...
```

Then, if it didn't open, here are some things that might be happening:

1. File doesn't exist.
2. File is not in the path you think it is.
3. You don't have the rights to access that file.

---

The problem lies in the file, since the code works fine, given that **the file** numbers.txt **exists** (and it's in the same directory with your executable file) I used that one for example:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

and the result is:

```
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ g++ main.cpp
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

---

And this is the code I used from you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class myClass {
public:
    void readFile() {
        ifstream read("numbers.txt");
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
           read>>sPerDay[i];

        for (int i = 0;i<10;i++) {
           cout << sPerDay[i] << " ";
        }
       cout << "\n";
    }

private:
    int sPerDay[10];

};


int main() {
    myClass obj;
    obj.readFile();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could be doing many things wrong.

1) The file `numbers.txt` does not exist, and this code fails to check that the file was successfully opened.

2) The file `numbers.txt` exists, but does not contain ten integer numbers, separated by whitespace, and this code fails to check whether `operator>>` succeeded, or not.

3) This code also prints ten numbers to `std::cout` without any separating character. At best, the output you will get is what looks line one large number.

So, there are at least two or three things that are wrong here. You need to fix all of them:

A) Verify that the file has been opened succesfully.

B) After every `operator>>` invocation, check if the file stream is `good()`, or not.